# StringUtils - Replace on the same line different words

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I read that using String.replaceAll is very slow. This how I do in old way:

```
String settence = "Java /*with*/ lambda /*expressions*/";
String replaceSettence = settence.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/*with*/"), "is").replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/*expressions*/"), "future");

System.out.println(replaceSettence);
```

How can I do this with StringUtils in one line?

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick answers.

I use code provided by Steph. My conclusion is that replaceAll is must faster that StringUtils:

```
  Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String settence = "Java /*with*/ lambda /*expressions*/";
        String replaceSettence = settence.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/*with*/"), "is").replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/*expressions*/"), "future");

        System.out.println(replaceSettence + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        String settenceStringUtils = "Java /*with*/ lambda /*expressions*/";
        String replaceStringUtils = StringUtils.replaceEach(settence, new String[]{"/*with*/", "/*expressions*/"}, new String[]{"is", "future"});
        System.out.println(replaceStringUtils + "StringUtils-> " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

Comment: Where did you read that `String.replace` is very slow?

Comment: @Reimeus , Exactly !! Goldbones will you provide source Where you read that ?

Comment: http://www.myhowto.org/under-the-hood/32-hidden-costs-of-using-java-string-methods/

Comment: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/string-replace-performance/

Comment: You can't conclude with just one call of each functions. You have to make several iterations with differents keywords/sentences and compute the time average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this:

```
String settence = "Java /*with*/ lambda /*expressions*/";
String replaceSettence = StringUtils.replaceEach(settence, new String[]{"/*with*/", "/*expressions*/"}, new String[]{"is","future"});
System.out.println(replaceSettence);
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace word Eg. text: "Princeton Group, Pa" => key:"inc", value:"" this will replace a substring and not a word

Comment: Yes, you can use space in regex to catch words. Or split your sentence by space and you will have an array of words so you are able to replace what you want.